# Google ReCaptcha failing on local xampp

Tags: php, recaptcha

I'm trying to implement Google's ReCaptcha v2 into my Homepage, but it doesnt work! I tried the [example](https://github.com/google/recaptcha/blob/master/examples/example-captcha.php) of their github project.
The error I get is:

> Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify): failed to open stream [...] in ...ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\Post.php on line 68

I looked up their code and checked if they're using curl and they do. Also I checked the allow_url_fopen and it's on!

Comment: It works only live domain, means not on local server.

Comment: Your file_get_contents works fine for me, from a 1-line php file running on localhost. Try a 1-line script, with just the URL you show above (but in quotes), and no other file_get_contents arguments.